# Document Image to display in Rich Text Field

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning

I have requirement to show images on my Stock object. For that, I have created a rich text field and also uploaded all the images inside a folder in Document object.

My ask is to upload the images on rich text field when user inserts the record. Name of document and a field value of Stock record should match to get the exact image.

Below is my code but I am not sure how to get the image from Document to Object record page.

```
   public class VW_ProductStockTriggerHandler {                                          
        public static void onBeforeInsert(List<SVMXC__Product_Stock__c>triggerNew) {
            string imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
            List<Document> lstDocument = [Select Id, Name, Body, DeveloperName from Document WHERE FolderId=:'00l8I000000aBErQAM'];
   for(SVMXC__Product_Stock__c productStock : triggerNew) {
       for(Document doc : lstDocument){
           if(productStock.GE_Water_SAP_Part_Number__c!=null && doc.Name==productStock.GE_Water_SAP_Part_Number__c){
               productStock.Image__c = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+doc.Id;
           }
       }
        }}}
```

Below is the screen shot if record page..
[image]

Image that needs to be uploaded from document object:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl()
```

Should be:

```
Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
```